# Accessing Database jobs from another schema in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have two schema "OWNER" and "USER".

I've created job in "OWNER" schema in PROD and we don't have access to login into this schema. Now I want to find a way to access these jobs in "USER" schema.

Below are the methods, I tried and did not work for me:
1)I created view in "OWNER" schema (create view test_view as select * from all_scheduler_jobs) and gave a grant "GRANT SELECT OWNER.test_view to USER". But still I did not find any records in USER schema.

2)Created a view as mentioned above and after that I created synonym in USER schema( create synonym  USER.test_view for OWNER.test_view.

Please let me know if there is anything that I'm missing or is there any other way that I can implement.

Comment: Create public synonym in OWNER schema and test simple select from the view in USER schema

Comment: HI @VBoka , public synonym didnot work as well..

Comment: Hi @OracleForLife, please can you share your select that you are executing from the USER schema?

Comment: SELECT * FROM OWNER.TEST_VIEW; and tried withSELECT * FROM TEST_VIEW as well but no luck...

Comment: Can you create the synonym without mentioning the schema. Like this:  create synonym test_view for OWNER.test_view

Comment: The view is created with *invoker* rights by default, meaning that `USER` is just selecting from the public `ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS` view with their own identity, not `OWNER`'s identity, and therefore still sees nothing.

Comment: Also, user schemas do not by default have the ability to grant privileges on underlying `SYS` objects like the `ALL_`, `USER_`, or `DBA_` views to other users. The `GRANT SELECT` command on your `TEST_VIEW` to `USER` should have generated an ORA-01720 error. What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Not able to create view with dba_Scheduler_jobs table in it. My view stmt is CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_VIEW AS SELECT * FORM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOS; throwing an error ora-01720 error. grant option does not exists for sys.dba_Scheduler_jobs

Answer (score 0):

The `ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS` view only lets you see jobs to which you already have access - essentially just your own. To see properties or output from scheduler jobs belonging to other schemas, `USER` must have the `SELECT ANY DICTIONARY` privilege, which would allow access to the `DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS` view. Check with your DBA to see if you are allowed to have that privilege (it opens up access to a lot of other things, too), or if they would prefer that you have a custom role that just grants access to the various `DBA_SCHEDULER_%` views. Note that these views would expose all jobs for all users, not just your `OWNER` schema; there isn't really a way to fine-tune that.

If `USER` needs to *execute* the job in another schema, then it will need the `EXECUTE ANY JOB` privilege, which would allow it to run *any* job in *any* schema. There's no way to make that more fine-grained at this time, either.

Comment: hi @pmdba, I gave SELCT ANY DICTIONARY grant but still did not work. If I create view with dba_scheduler_jobs table then I'm getting error ora-01720 (grant option is missing on sys.dba_scheduler_jobs table). and If I create view with all/user_scheduler_jobs table then I'm not able see any job records in another schema(user) of original(owner) schema.

Comment: @OracleForLife having the `select any dictionary` privilege, did you select from `DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS`?

Comment: My DBA is not ready to provide 'SELECT ANY DICTIONARY' grant. Is there any alternative for this?

Answer (score -1):

You can try below SQL.

SCHEMA: OWNER

```
commit;
```

SCHEMA: USER

```
select * from OWNER.test_view;
```

Comment: This did not work for me

Comment: @OracleForLife An implicit commit would have been executed when you created the view in the first place. This is redundant and wouldn't change anything.